# Why is void not covariant in Java?

Tags: java, polymorphism, covariance

If I have this interface:

```
public interface Foo {
    void bar();
}
```

Why can't I implement it like this?

```
public class FooImpl implements Foo {
    @Override
    public Object bar() {
         return new Object();
    }
}
```

It seems like void should be covariant with everything.  Am I missing something?

Edit:
I should have been clearer that I'm looking for the design justification, not the technical reason that it won't compile.  Are there negative consequences to making void covariant to everything?

Comment: The JLS is pretty clear about that, but maybe someone could provide a technical reason why it may be designed this way. I guess `void` could be a supertype of `Object` with no defined methods. Would make this example work at least. I don't know if it's worth the added complexity.

Comment: @atamanroman Because `void` explicitly means *nothing*; it's a contract stating the method has no return value. Being able to return something would violate that contract--it's just the way it was designed.

Comment: @DaveNewton there is other no example in the rest of the Java type system of placing an upper bound on a return.  What you're saying is an argument against covariant return types in general.  "`Object` explicitly means _Object_; it's a contract stating that the method has to return an Object and nothing more".  So my question remains - is there a good reason to not consider `void` a supertype of everytype (at least for the purpose of return covariance)?

Comment: @MattWallace How is saying "void explicitly means nothing", which is what it means, anything other than just that?! What you're saying isn't what the JLS says, what I said is. But yes, there is a good reason-to allow the definition of a method that explicitly doesn't return anything. If void was a supertype how would you indicate a method will not ever return something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically `void` cannot be a covariant return type as the caller needs to know the stack layout.
Calling a function that returns an object would result of an object-ref on the top of the stack after the INVOKEVIRTUAL/INTERFACE. `Void` return type leaves nothing on the top of the stack, hence the functions are binary incompatible.

So the JLS rightfully says it's not possible.

Answer (score 13):

`void` is only covariant with `void` because [the JLS says so](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.5):

> A method declaration d1 with return type R1 is
>   return-type-substitutable for another method d2 with return type R2,
>   if and only if the following conditions hold:
>
> - **If R1 is `void` then R2 is `void`.**
> - If R1 is a primitive type, then R2 is identical to R1.
> - If R1 is a reference type then:
>
>   - R1 is either a subtype of R2 or R1 can be converted to a subtype of R2
>       by unchecked conversion (§5.1.9), or
>   - R1 = |R2|

Answer (score 5):

**covariance** means that if your methods `return type` is a `Supertype object` you can return `sub-type Object` at runtime, **void** is not the `super type of java.lang.Object`(or any Object for that matter except itself as answered by MR NPE)

Answer (score 1):

`void` effectively means that it returns nothing. You may be getting confused with a `void *` in C/C++. If you change the interface to be

```
public interface Foo {
    Object bar();
}
```

it will work fine because all objects in Java inherit `Object`.

So, you could do something like this:

```
public class FooImpl implements Foo {

    @Override
    public Object bar() {
         return new SpecialObject();
    }

}

SpecialObject obj = (SpecialObject) new FooImpl().bar();
```

Answer (score 1):

Return types must match for overridden methods.

```
Foo foo = new FooImpl();
foo.bar();
```

Unless all implementations comply with the interface and return the same object  (or nothing at all) how do I know what that will return?

Answer (score 1):

`void` is not part of the java file system.

If we do make it a type, it's more like an empty type, so it should be a subtype of every other type, i.e. it is contra-variant with other types.

In your example, the super class dictates that nothing should be returned, yet the subclass returns something, therefore the subclass violates the superclass's contract.

`Object` is covariant with other types, if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

A covariant return type usually means the one that can be replaced by a narrower type. In `Java`, there is no such relation (supertype-subtype) between `void` and `Object` or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

If this were allowed, there would be no way to determine if this should compile or not.

```
 Foo foo = ...
 Object o = foo.bar(); // is it void or an Object ?
```

Comment: Of course it wouldn't compile, because you're accessing it through `Foo`. Just like `new FooImpl() { public String bar() { return super.bar(); } };` wouldn't compile even though `return this.bar()` would.