# could one day the JVM "void return type only" become a self call chaining new capability?

Tags: java, jvm

**could one day the JVM "void return type only" become a self call chaining new capability?**

**1) this would be about allowing anything to be returned:** but may be not so good, as the commenters say

If not, why? why it is a good reason to never allow that below?

```
class A{
//    public Object a(){return null;}
  public void a(){}
}
class B extends A{
  @Override
    public String a(){return "";}; //error
}
```

**2) this is about self call chaining, restricted usage, would be much better/safer/clearer option**

Why I want that? to let setters be chain linked like: `new B().set1(1).set2(2).set3(3);` using [getThis() trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655335/method-chaining-how-to-use-getthis-trick-in-case-of-multi-level-inheritance)

**void return** is so useless, it would break nothing because it is already ignored by everything!

As we wont have access to most setters of libraries, and dont want to fork them all, the real deal would be to let void (or Void?) become Object I guess. **Or even better, become a new restricted type called "? extends Self" letting the getThis() trick be part of the JVM core.**. So this would be a restricted use case, only alowing self chaining calls.

Why a high level language (then assembler) cant allow this covariance "law breaking" capability/option? If we call a method that returns something and ignore/do not capture it, it will work equivalently to a void return!
So the otherwise back functionality could be allowed bringing new light to where once there was nothing but a desert of options.

So, this is the real deal, where a setter returning void would leave us no options:

```
class A<SELF extends A>{
//  public void set(){} //this one leaves us no options
  public SELF set(){return getThis();}
    public SELF getThis(){return (SELF)this;}
}
class B extends A<B>{
  @Override public B set(){return getThis();}
  @Override public B getThis(){return this;}
}
```

Basically, I am not looking for an opinion, I am looking for a good reason/explanation.

so, I understand I am further argumenting beyond the requests of this question: [Why is void not covariant in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219529/why-is-void-not-covariant-in-java)

Comment: There is never a good reason to fundamentally change the semantics of the language or to relax semantic rules that software has been relying on for decades. Go ahead and suggest it but you'll get the same answer.

Comment: @EJP void return is so useless, it would break nothing because it is already ignored by everything

Comment: The idea makes sense to me, but it doesn't change the fact that it's an opinion-based question. *why I should not go right now suggest that to JVM developers* -- no one's saying you shouldn't, but don't expect any results...

Comment: @shmosel fixed b4 the close team come by, thx :)

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219529/why-is-void-not-covariant-in-java

Comment: @shmosel I tried at A with `public Void a(){return null;}` but didnt work at B?

Comment: @shmosel thinking again, I am still reading there, I am looking for the root reason they do not allow it to be circunvented in a high level language compared to assembler. let me keep reading to be sure, may be I change the considerations here enough to distinguish between them

Comment: I'd say the most accurate answer is this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14219599/1553851. Anything further is opinion and speculation.

Comment: @shmosel yes, I read that, and the main argument is "because JLS says so" and that is not an argument to me, in a sense that we are using a high level language compared to assembler...

Comment: Why isn't it a valid argument? What does a high level language have to do with anything?

Comment: It would break type safety to do as you propose. Java is a strongly-typed language. That will never change.

Comment: @shmosel in bash scripts we do not constraint a return type, and whatever is output can be captured in "any format", thats a quite high level language, more than java. A change that would not break any application, but would still bring new functionalities to the table of options, would be mostly welcome.

Comment: @LewBloch but void is "type less" nothing would break during a cast, because before the override, nothing was expecting anything to be captured. Could you exemplify?

Comment: @shmosel I think I can distinguish this question because of the chain linking of setters using the getThis() trick. see what I addeed in the end.

Comment: No, it is not typeless. It's got the special "void" type, which per http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2 is not return-type substitutable for other types. For `void` to allow a pseudo-covariant reference type in overrides would break, among other things, type inference used by lambdas​. Wouldn't that be pretty?

Comment: Put another way, a `void` return type is a _promise_ not to return a value. Allowing a subtype to return a value would break that promise. It isn't just that callers ignore a return type, they count on the promise that there is none. Allowing that to change would undercut the fundamental strongly-typed nature of Java. Type promises are what Java is all about.

Comment: @LewBloch I just imagined a new type to replace void, it would be called "? extends Self" so, it would be used exclusively to provide chain linked self calls. Would that be acceptable? not to be captured as an int or string, but exclusively to self call the object. It would be like letting the getThis() trick become a permanent part of JVM.

Comment: @LewBloch *Put another way, a `void` return type is a promise not to return a value.* What's your basis for that interpretation? And why do you think `void` covariance would break any code? Any caller looking at the supertype would still see `void`. You would only see a return type from the subclass, just like with polymorphic covariance.

Comment: As @shmosel said, covariance for `void` would not create any technical problems. Neither would a chaining of setters feature handled at language level. That wouldn’t even need any JVM changes. Though I’d prefer something like `using(new B()) { set1(1); set2(2); set3(3); }` as that would even work with non-`void` methods and support other language constructs beyond simple linear chains of method invocations.

Comment: @Holger that option looks really good, you mean tools like [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/)?

Comment: That could be a language feature.

Comment: @Holger omg... we can already do that!!! but only for new anonymous instances... here: `Tst tst = new Tst(){{
   a();
   System.out.println(b());
  }};`

Comment: @Aquarius Power: but creating an entirely new class just for saving a few characters in source code, is not an option to me. Not to mention the other implications, like capturing the outer `this` instance in an object not meant to hold that reference, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Java does support *covariant return types*. For instance:

```
class A {
    Object run() { ... }
}

class B {
    String run() {...}
}
```

As such, your chained setters example is possible using overriding (or generics). But the resulting code might not feel like idiomatic Java.

Comment: Not really an answer, just an ugly workaround.

Comment: I dont have access to most setters of libraries, I wont fork them, the real deal would be to let void become Object I guess.

Comment: @AquariusPower I agree. You would need non-void, non-final methods from your superclass... and the willing to override them all :)

Answer (score 1):

Because of the basic laws of inheritance. Specifically, the Liskov substitution principle in SOLID:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design) 
“objects in a program should be replaceable with instances of their subtypes without altering the correctness of that program.”

By changing the return type, the subclass would not follow this principle. Calling `b.a()` would not return void, but a String instead.

I can't think of any specific problems in the specific case of methods that return void and later get overridden to return something else, but that's such an odd case that I'd be concerned that people would abuse it and my Class D that extends A returns an int on D.a() and now everyone's confused.

**Because when I tell my fellow programmers that I'm calling method a() of some subclass of A, they know what it's going to return.**

```
class A{ 
//    public Object a(){return null;} 
  public void a(){} 
} 
class B extends A{ 
  @Override 
    public String a(){return "";}; //error
} 
class C extends A{
  @Override 
    public int a(){return 0;}; //error
}
```

Now what does method a() do? How do I communicate with my team in a sensible manner about this method?

Now imagine I have this:

```
List<A> listOfAs = new ArrayList<>();
```

What happens when I call `listOfAs.get(0).a() / 2`?

Comment: That's not true. No caller of `A.a()` expects a return type, and no expectations are violated. By your logic, any covariant return type would violate LSP.

Comment: @shmosel, I have edited my answer and I think you may find it worth reconsidering.

Comment: I read your edit, reconsidered, and failed to see any merit in your argument.

Comment: I think they would become surprised, not confused because things didnt change, in a sense that there was something now there is something else, but in a sense that, there was nothing in that desert, now there is a place to drink and rest, an oasis :)

Comment: Nothing changes from the perspective of the superclass. It's only if you drill into the subclasses that you see the differences, which is part of the very nature of inheritance. You could make the same arguments about return type covariance in general, which *is* supported by Java.

Comment: You're using very vague terminology to express your point: *Now what does method a() do? What happens when I call `listOfAs.a().get(0) / 2`?* What the method does is whatever is in the implementation. What happens when you try to get a return value from a `void` method? Well, it doesn't compile, obviously. Also, I think you meant `listOfAs.get(0).a()`.

Comment: Callers of a `void` method do expect the return type not to change, and covariant return types do not break Liskov substitution.