# Why is Void not the bottom type in Java?

Tags: java, types, null, void, bottom-type

If the only element of the type [`Void`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Void.html) is `null`, and `null` is an element of every reference type in Java, why is `Void` not considered a subtype of every reference type? **Other than legacy, are there reasons why `Void` should *not* be the [bottom type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type) in Java?**

Note: I'm looking for a design justification (if there is one), not just "because the JLS says so".

---

### Potential use case: empty collections

A typical use case for the bottom type is to type an empty list. Given two unrelated classes `A` and `B`, consider the following two method signatures.

```
float processAs(List<? extends A> as) { ... }
float processBs(List<? extends B> bs) { ... }
```

Note that I made the list parameters 'covariant' using a wildcard. Now, for some list `List<C> cs` where `C` is any subtype of `A`, I'm still able to call `processAs(cs)`. (analogously for `processBs`) Suppose now that we have an empty list `List<...> empty = Collections.emptyList();`. Depending on which type I fill in for the dots, I can call `processAs` when it is a subtype of `A` or call `processBs` when it is a subtype of `B`, but not both. Yet, nothing unsafe can happen if I would be able to pass it to both. If `Void` was considered the bottom type, we could type it as `List<Void>` and I could write `processAs(empty)` and `processBs(empty)` with no problem.

This would work much like the [`Nothing`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/Nothing.html) type in Scala, where lists are considered covariant too.

---

### A bit of context

I'm writing a code translator from a language called Nouga (not released yet) to Java. In Nouga, there is a bottom type called `nothing`. The `Void` type seemed the most appropriate translation for that. Although I can work around the mistranslation of the subtype relation using coercions, it still made me curious whether there are reasons why `Void` should *not* be considered the bottom type.

---

Possibly related: [Why is void not covariant in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14219529/3083982) But this questions seems to be more about a confusion between covariance and contravariance (i.e., the OP uses `void` as if it were the top type, not the bottom type).

Comment: This statement about Scala's `Nothing`: _...at the bottom of Scala's type hierarchy_ seems misleading since Scala's `Nothing` extends Scala's `Any`. So which is really the bottom type?  From a java perspective since `Void` represents, well, void, it doesn't make sense (at least to me) to extend from java's `Void` (let alone it be java's bottom type).  Perhaps Nouga'a `Nothing` is akin to java's `Object` rather than java's `Void`.

Comment: @AndrewS Thanks for the comment. I think there is some confusion though. Three remarks. (1) `Any` is the top type in Scala, so as any other type, the bottom type `Nothing` extends from it. (2) From a Java prespective, you would indeed *not* extend `Void`; rather `Void` would be an extension of everything. That's what it means to be the bottom type. (3) `Object` in Java is the top type, so that actually corresponds to Scala's `Any` type. In Nouga there is no top type.